# How do I convert List to Map where the key is one of the properties and value is the object using Collector

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I want to convert List to Map something like this:

```
List<Student> to Map<String, Student>
```

Specifically I want the key to be property of the Student object which is student id and the value to be the entire Student object. I want to use java 8 Stream Collector. I need something like:

```
Collectors.toMap(Strudent::getId, Student)
```

I can make a map from one property of the object to another property of the same object like Collectors.toMap(Strudent::getId, Student:getName) but I want the entire Student object as value.

Comment: Just use an identity function `x -> x`. So, `Collectors.toMap(Strudent::getId, x -> x)`

Comment: x->x solved my problem. thanks